# Placing arrows in tikz functions

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'm trying to get this representation:
[image]

but I'm having some trouble:

[image]

I'm trying to:

- Make arrows bigger, as shown in the hand-drawn function
- Get function + arrow in just one `\addplot` line
- Get the legend entries as shown in the hand-drawn function

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotsset{my style1/.append style={clip = false, axis lines* = middle, axis equal, xtick = \empty, ytick = \empty}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows} 

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[my style1, legend pos=outer north east, samples=200]
            \addplot [red, domain=-2:1] ({x},{0.5*sqrt(4-x^2)});
            \addlegendentry {$\gamma_1$};   
            \addplot [<-, red, domain=1:2] ({x},{0.5*sqrt(4-x^2)});
            
            \addplot [->, blue, domain=-2:-1] ({x},{-0.5*sqrt(4-x^2)}); 
            \addplot [blue, domain=-1:2] ({x},{-0.5*sqrt(4-x^2)});
            \addlegendentry {$\gamma_2$};
            
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of `arrows` you should use preferred `arrows.meta`. This package enable high customizing of the arrows head. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\pgfplotsset{my style1/.style={clip = false, 
                               axis lines* = middle,
                               axis equal,
                               xtick = \empty, ytick = \empty,
  every axis plot post/.append style = {thick}} % thickness of function,
                                                % if you like to change curve thickness
            }
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
> = {Straight Barb[line width=2pt, length=2mm]}% define arrow head features
                        ]
\begin{axis}[my style1, legend pos=outer north east, samples=200]
            \addplot [red, domain=-2:1] {0.5*sqrt(4-x^2)};
            \addplot [<-, red, domain=1:2] {0.5*sqrt(4-x^2)};

            \addplot [->, blue, domain=-2:-1] {-0.5*sqrt(4-x^2)};
            \addplot [blue, domain=-1:2]{-0.5*sqrt(4-x^2)};
        \legend{$\gamma_1$,,,$\gamma_2$}; % <---
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

In the first I didn't bother with legend, but now, after @ferahfeza comment (thank you very much), here is solution:

- delete all `\addlegendentry {...}`;
- replace them by `\legend{$\gamma_1$,,,$\gamma_2$};` before `\end{axis}`
- now above MWE is corrected accordingly and result is:

[image]

**Addendum:**
for fun and to show another possibility, how to draw your function:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\pgfplotsset{my style1/.style={clip = false, 
                               axis lines* = middle,
                               axis equal,
                               xtick = \empty, ytick = \empty,
  every axis plot post/.append style = {very thick}% thickness of function,
                                                   % if you like to change default value
                               }                               
            }
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.markings
                }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
->-/.style={decoration={markings,% switch on markings
                        mark=at position 0.75 with {\arrow[line width=2pt]{Straight Barb}}
                        },
            postaction={decorate}
            }
                        ]
\begin{axis}[
    my style1, 
    legend pos=outer north east, 
    samples=101]
\addplot [->-, red,  domain=2:-2] { 0.5*sqrt(4-x^2)};
\addplot [->-, blue, domain=-2:2] {-0.5*sqrt(4-x^2)};
        \legend{$\gamma_1$,$\gamma_2$};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would slightly increase the thickness of the curve. There is too much discrepancy between the thickness and the size of the arrowhead. +1

Comment: What do you think about legend entry?

Comment: @ferahfeza, I left it as OP design it. To my opinion it is not consistent. I will give a look, how to correct them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for discovering me ```arrows.meta```. Constructive answer, +1. Please read @ferahfeza comment, @Zarko

Comment: @Zarko your answer is a pleasure. You have met all my requirements and a lot more. Thanks for the detailed explanations and for the addendum with ->- definition, its so edifying

Comment: @Á.Iborra, you are welcome!